# Elasticsearch - Create report filters using Bool (MUST & AND) DSL query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to create some report filters where the user can search for profiles using any fields on the report. For example: search for any profile with `firstname` that starts with `ann` and `grade` that starts with `vi` etc.

Here is a query I have written so far:

```
{
    from: 20,
    size: 20,
    query: {
        filtered: {
            query: {
                match_all: [ ]
            },
            filter: {
                bool: {
                    must: [
                        {
                            prefix: {
                                firstname: "ann"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            prefix: {
                                grade: "vi"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
       }
   },
   sort: {
       grade: {
           order: "asc"
       }
   }
}
```

If I remove one child of `must` (in the `bool` filter), it works. But it doesn't return any results once I use more than one filters and I need to be able to use any number of entries in there.

Also, if I use `should` instead of `must`, it works. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the logic, but to my understanding (in this case) `must` should return ONLY results with `firstname` that starts with `ann` and `grade` that starts with `vi`.

They do exist, but this query just doesn't find them.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: The query looks fine and your understanding of how it should work is correct. So, it is probably something with your mapping or fieldnames, or something else you assume is set up correctly but isn't. Try to create a minimal example that breaks using a sample document and query. An empty index and two curl commands should do the trick in confirming there is nothing wrong with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, I cannot post comments yet. I'm answering with some assumptions.

First of all, I'm using `ES 0.90.2 version` and your query works fine for my inputs. However, depending on your input size and the platform that you executed your query, my answer may not be the right one.

**Assumption**: Number of data in the index is less than 20.

I've added following inputs to my index:

```
'{"name": "ann", "grade": "vi"}'
'{"name": "ann", "grade": "ii"}'
'{"name": "johan", "grade": "vi"}'
'{"name": "johan", "grade": "ii"}'
```

And my test query was the same as yours, and here is the result:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]          // <-- see this part is blank
  }
```

As you can see, it didn't listed hits, but there are two hits. That's because of the `from:20` code segment. If you change that value, you can see some results. If you want to see all results just delete that part.

Note: Well if this is not the case, sorry for bothering :(

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but I tested without pagination and didn't get any results. I also tried it using Curl on command line, but no luck. I still get `'total':0`.

Comment: What is your index settings(analyzers&mapping)? I used default_analyzer, that could be the problem.

Comment: I found the issue. I was really being a boob this time: 
I've been trying to retrieve records with different schemers. Record A  has the field `firstname`, but doesn't have the field `grade`. Record B has `grade`, but doesn't have `firstname`. I was somehow trying to aggregate that. That means I might have to use `should` and then combine the the records in code somehow, which is an entirely different question. Right? I'm guessing this is not possible in ElastcSearch alone?

Comment: How many document do you have in your index? If it's not that much, you can delete all the data and re-index your data or without deleting overwrite it with versioning feature, but still you have to delete some dummy data. Besides these, I don't know another solution that you can merge these documents.

Comment: Thanks Shyos. It's just that these documents are automatically indexed by Couchbase, so I kinda have no control over their schema, unless I change the way I store documents in Couchbase.